Create a SharePoint online site using Power Automate flow - Can i use a custom site design already in the tenant?
I'm required to create a way for users to be able to create sites (self service).
I'm using a form with a power automate.
I have created a site script and a site design.
When i follow the instructions here using Power automate
Its using the OOTB site design. The question is will it be also use a custom site design i have created in the tenant?
I tried using a GUID for my custom site design but it seems not to work.
Any ideas?

Please try by passing your body in power automate action as shown below:
{
    "request": {
        "Title": "My Communication Site",
        "Url": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/MyCommSite",
        "Description": "My Communication Site created using Power Automate flow",
        "Owner": "abc@contoso.com",
        "Lcid": 1033,
        "WebTemplate": "SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0",
        "SiteDesignId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "ShareByEmailEnabled": false,
        "WebTemplateExtensionId":"6142d2a0-63a5-4ba0-aede-d9fefca2c767",
    }
}

We need to pass our custom site design id in WebTemplateExtensionId property.
Reference link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/site-creation-rest
